# SQL: Group multiple records by ID and get initial and end date based on date field

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
+-----------+------------+
| client_id | reg_date   |
+-----------+------------+
| 1         | 01-01-2021 |
+-----------+------------+
| 1         | 01-06-2021 |
+-----------+------------+
| 2         | 01-01-2021 |
+-----------+------------+
```

I need a new table, with the init_reg_date and end_reg_date per client_id, something like this:

| client_id | init_reg_date | end_reg_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2021 | 01-06-2021 |
| 2 | 01-01-2021 |  |

Is there any way to do this with SQL?

Thanks to all!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Column reg_date data type? Does 01-06-2021 mean January 6:th, or June 1:st?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use a `case` expression to return the latest date for a client only if it's not the same date as the client's first date.

```
select client_id,
       min(reg_date) as init_reg_date,
       case when max(reg_date) > min(reg_date) then max(reg_date) end as end_reg_date
from tablename
group by client_id
```

You can even simplify this a bit using `NULLIF`. (*if the operands are equal, the NULLIF expression has the value null, otherwise it has the value of the first operand.*)

```
select client_id,
       min(reg_date) as init_reg_date,
       NULLIF(max(reg_date), min(reg_date)) as end_reg_date
from tablename
group by client_id
```